# What local node-version is recommended for AWS Lambda and Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Starting with AWS-Lambda and the Serverless Framework i am confused about node versions:

The [AWS help site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) says that (on 21-March-2016)

> AWS Lambda supports the following runtime versions:
>
> Node.js: v0.10.36

So i did install Node.js v0.10.36 on my local machine. Installing the latest (v 0.4.2) serverless framework via

```
npm install serverless -g
```

it gives the following warning:

> npm WARN engine serverless@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=4.0"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})

I thought having the same version locally as on AWS might help having a consistent development environment... Am i wrong? What Node.js version should i run locally to get the most out of serverless?

Comment: You need to install serverless version that supports node v0.10.36

Comment: How can i check, that it does?

Comment: you'd better ask the contributors of this package regarding that, or check the versions yourself

Comment: @Floo0, I am running node v5.1.0 on my machine and serverless v0.4.2. The only problematic thing for me was ECMA 2015. I would suggest to install node versions as sls asks "node":">=4.0". I have not heard anyone in the community struggling with this version mismatch. I am not saying it is perfect, people are still waiting for Lambda team to update node version.

Comment: @AluaK Thank you very much. Just updated my node version. So far everything works

Comment: **Update** August 2017: 

> AWS Lambda currently supports the following Node.js runtimes:

* Node.js runtime v6.10 (runtime = nodejs6.10)
* Node.js runtime v4.3 (runtime = nodejs4.3)
* Node v0.10.42 is currently marked as deprecated.        

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html

Answer (score 6):

The Serverless Framework requires Node.js v4.0 or higher. Any version of Node.js within the v4.x or v5.x lines should work.

You are correct that AWS Lambda currently only supports Node.js v0.10.36. The decision to build the Serverless Framework on Node.js v4.0 was done in anticipation that AWS Lamabda would eventually support Node.js v4.0 or higher.

When developing code for AWS Lambda, you should continue to only use features compatible with Node.js v0.10.36. If you make any contributions to the framework, you can use Node.js features available in v4.0+.

Another option is to use [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) to transform your ES2015 code uploading to AWS Lambda. This allows you to develop in ES2015 without having to wait for AWS Lambda to officially support it. This can be done automatically each time you deploy with the Serverless Framework using the [Optimizer Plugin](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-optimizer-plugin).

Update: A new option now exists, the [Serverless Babel Runtime](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-runtime-babel). This goes one step beyond what Optimizer does, and uses Babel inside the runtime itself.

Update 2: AWS Lambda now supports Node.js v4.3.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So far i am amazed of the ease to use serverless. Great job!

Comment: Lambda support Node 4.3 now (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-4-3-2-runtime-now-available-on-lambda/) and I have runtime set to nodejs4.3 in my s-function.json file, but I get errors when I try to use 4.3 features (eg fat arrow functions, template strings, generators to name a few). Is serverless forcing me to use non-ES2015 features somehow?

Comment: Turns out my lambda function has been created to use node0.10 initially (I was toying around with the serverless babel plugin) and serverless didn't update the configuration on AWS even though I had changed the runtime to nodejs4.3 in my s-function.json and redeployed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting out with a brand new, fresh project I would highly avoid starting with node 0.10.x. That version is just receiving important security fixes at this point, and only for another five months (until October 2016).

The Node.js has adopted the common Long Term Support (LTS) pattern to keep releases timely and stable. [Here is the current LTS plan](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/) for node.

I would highly recommend starting out with version 4 or 5, depending on your appetite for change and keeping your project up to date. You will be able to take advantage of [numerous new features](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/) over the 0.10/0.12 releases as well as better prepare you for [ES6](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/).